# Is there a simple(r) way to play Youtube video by URL? (IFrame API)

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

If you want to [load Youtube video by URL](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoByUrl) in an iframe you should use a strictly formatted link, which looks like this:
`http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3`

The matter is that URLs are usually inputted by real people (content creators). And they get URLs from the most accessible places, such as:

- browser address bar
- via sharing buttons

And the URLs often look like these:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX
- https://youtu.be/XXXXXXXXXXX
- https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/XXXXXXXXXXX
- there might be other, I guess…

### And then we have a couple of scenarios ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ3mN.png)):

**A: loadVideoById()**
get video URL → parse URL to get id → loadVideoById(id)

**B: loadVideoByUrl()**
get video URL → parse URL to get id → generate strict URL with id → loadVideoByUrl(URL)

*I don't understand the scenario "**B**", why it is needed at all? It would be more useful for developers to have the scenario "**C**".*

**C: loadVideoByUrl()**
get video URL → loadVideoByUrl(URL)

I don't believe that Youtube cannot parse their own URLs. But for now, I'm doing it via regex manually and individually for each URL type specified in the list above.

**So, the question is:**
Is there something I don't know and there are ways to use any youtube URL to load the video?

If no, then, does anybody know where I can post an issue/ticket request regarding the Youtube IFrame API?

Thank you in advance.